# no puedo formatear el codigo. pycodestyle no me funciona en Visual Code

Tags: python, vscode

Tengo un problema al momento de formatear en pep8 (pycodestyle)
Dejo de funcionarme de un dia para otro y no entiendo por que?

necesito ayuda please.

Aquí dejo el código de la configuracion:

```
{
"python.defaultInterpreterPath": "C:\\Users\\Keeper Lifeblood\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python310\\python.exe",
"python.linting.enabled": true,
"editor.formatOnSave": true,
"editor.minimap.enabled": false,
"workbench.colorTheme": "Dracula Soft",
"python.linting.flake8Enabled": true,
"python.linting.pycodestyleEnabled": true,
"editor.fontWeight": "normal"
```

Comment: La opción `"python.defaultInterpreterPath"` ya no se usa. Asegúrate que el intérprete que usa tu proyecto sea el que tiene instalado `pycodestyle`. Abre la terminal en vscode y búscalo (eg: con un `where pycodestyle`). Otra opción más sencilla es elegir el "linter" desde el _Command Palette_ (Ctrl+Shift+P), comando **Python: Select Linter** y dejar que vscode te lo instale en el entorno python en uso.

Comment: no entiendo exactamente como hacer lo primero que me dices para ubicar el pycodestyle. 

hice lo de seleccionar el Linter desde el Command Palette, pero nada, no formatea sin importar cual seleccione.

Comment: Con el comando `where` localiza dónde tienes instalado `python.exe` y `pycodestyle.exe`. Así mismo, asegúrate del intérprete de python que usas en vscode usando el comando en el _command palette_.

Comment: creo que ya me funciona sin necesidad de instalar pycodestyle.